# Javascript Ajax: how to get the Id of something?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi, grpc

Right now I'm trying to do a simple delete / update / get through the User Id but I'm not getting the data correctly and I don't know if it's because of the ajax function, if it's for my web Api or if it's because of gRPC ,

My question is similar to this link I already asked, so I'll maybe show the simplest part which is the delete and also show the ajax call

Old Link: [gRPC and/or WebAPI: How to do a simple Update but using an Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474921/grpc-and-or-webapi-how-to-do-a-simple-update-but-using-an-id)

gRPC Delete:

```
public override async Task<Empty> Delete(UserFilter requestData,
                ServerCallContext context)
        {
            var data = await _context.Users_5.FindAsync(requestData.UserID);
            
            if(date == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("User Not Found");
            }
            _context.Users_5.Remove(data);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return await Task.FromResult(new Empty());
        }
```

WebApi:

```
[HttpDelete("{Id_user}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Empty>> DeleteUser([FromBody] UserFilter Id_user)
        {
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Request Received for AuthController::Delete");
            /**
            if(Id_user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Id not Found idk why");
            }

            if(Id_user.ToString() != Request.Cookies["LoginUserId"])
            {
                return BadRequest("Id's is Different");
            }
            */
            var results = await _userClient.DeleteAsync(Id_user);

            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Sending Response from AuthController::Delete");

            return Ok(results);
        }
```

The Javascript Code:

```
var $users_A = $('#users_A');
var $Id_user = $('#Id_user')


$users_A.delegate('.remove', 'click', function () {
        var $li = $(this).closest('li');
        var self = this;
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            
            url: uri_7 + $Id_user,
            type: 'DELETE',
            
            success: function() {
                $li.fadeOut(300, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('XHR:' + JSON.stringify(xhr) + '\nTextStatus:' + textStatus + '\nErrorThrown:' + errorThrown);
                
            }

        });
    });
```

The stupid error:

> XHR:{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title" :"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-82ac37132e06d497f2f7ec082e382273-ba6109fbfa7fd9f8-00","errors":{"$\ ":["The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],"Id_user":["The Id_user field is required."]}}","responseJSON":{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/ html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-82ac37132e06d497f2f7ec082e382273-ba6109fbfa7fd9f8-00","errors":{ "$":["The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],"Id_user": ["The Id_user field is required."]}},"status":400,"statusText":"error"}

--Conclusion--

Idk what's happening, I have the post and the getAllUsers correct but getting a specific user it gives me a lot of pain, so how to correct this code??

Any Answer/Help is always welcome

Comment: `$('#IdUser')` is probably some DOM-Element so `url: uri_7 + $Id_user` may not produce the result you are expecting ...  Furthermore, your action on the backend expects a JSON body, but your ajax request on the frontend doesn't send any body at all ...

Comment: [`delegate`](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/) was deprecated in version 3.0. Consider switching to [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), which has been the preferred method since version 1.7.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I personally see very little reason to use jQuery for new projects anyways ...

Comment: @derpirscher Sure, same here, but if you're going to use it, might as well use it correctly.

Comment: @derpirscher like in the frontend method add something like 'function (data)' in the sucess ajax call? And also I need to have something like a $Id_User so the delete method recognize that i want to delete a specific user, the Id_User i have also in html like this -> <button data-id='{{ Id_user }}' class="remove">Delete</button> .  Can you give a mini example of what is the DOM-Element and how to correct that?

Comment: I only find JQuery and delegate in the examples, so for new projects so what do you recommend me other than jQuery?

Comment: @JoséLeal I don't know what your DOM looks like, but probably at some point you have something like `<div id="IdUser">somecontent</div>` or `<input id='IdUser>` and that's what you get back from `$("#IdUser')`

Comment: To be honest: You seem to have very little development knowledge, so it might be impossible here to guide you through your development process. Maybe you should find and work through some basic (and current! ie not from 2016!) tutorials first to get straight with the basics

Comment: I don't have any div or input with the id='Id_User', just in the button and that should give me the specific 'Id_User', so in the uri will give me the complete path (ex: controller/auth/{Id_User}) and this calls me the method in web api correct. The problem can't be in html I think, or is in the javascript or in the web api

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the UserFilter model? Besides, have you tried to use [FromUri]

Comment: @Brando Zhang the UserFilter is a message from gRPC with a simple string like this "message UserFilter {string userID = 1;}" , also what does the [FromUri]?

Comment: According to your case, it seems you have two server endpoint, one is GRPC and another is web api right?

Comment: @Brando Zhang I already corrected the error, I used something similar to [FromUri] (I used [FromRoute] because it was a .Net Core application) so thank you anyway because part of the help came through this [FromUri]

Comment: And Yes, I have a endpoint in gRPC and other in Web Api